# How to filter sting with "[" and "]" inside using grep?

Tags: grep

How to filter anything inside `"<torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA["` and `"]]></torrent:magnetURI>"` so it would output the string "EXAMPLE" using grep?

```
<torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA[EXAMPLE]]></torrent:magnetURI>
```

I'm trying to get all the magnet url in the web and add them to transmission.

```
for url in $(wget -q -O- "http://sample.com/rss.xml" | grep -o '<torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA["[^"]*' | grep -o '[^>]*$'); do 
transmission-remote localhost:9091 -a "$url"; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=<torrent:magnetURI><!\[CDATA\[)\w*(?=\]\]>)' file
EXAMPLE
```

Note it is using a look behind and look forward `(?<=before)\w*(?=after)`, also escaping the `[`:

```
(?<=<torrent:magnetURI><!\[CDATA\[)\w*(?=\]\]>)
   ------------------------------- ---   -----
       string to find before        |    string after
                            string matched
```

Comment: when i use the code i get an error `grep: invalid option -- P`.